# getElementsByTagName("LI") not pulling Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

i have problem with getting data from ("LI").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>An unordered list:</p>
<div>
  <li>40</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>10</li>
</div>

<p>Click the button to display the innerHTML of the second li element (index 1).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>

function myFunction() {
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var noh = parseInt(y[0].innerHTML);
var nom = parseInt(y[1].innerHTML);
var nos = parseInt(y[2].innerHTML);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = noh;

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var s = parseInt(x[1].innerHTML);
var t = 5;
var tot = s+t;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tot+noh;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is working when I run it on w3school site, but it is showing error on `parseInt(y[0].**innerHTML**)`;

error is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

Can anyone please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `LI` must  be the child of `UL` or `OL`, Your HTML is invalid

Comment: your attached demo is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with lowercase "li" instead, because your code is working just fine for me in Chrome, which could mean that your browser is case sensitive when searching for elements.

Comment: tag name case in these contexts don't matter.  Only context I know where it does is that `tagName` property had some weird consistency issues in older versions of IE.